# How to change theme in ASP.Net MVC 5 based on Hosted Url

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to change MVC theme dynamically based on hosted same project with diffrent url.

Eg:

localhost/SiteA/Account/Login

localhost/SiteB/Account/Login

localhost/SiteC/Account/Login

Here SiteA, SiteB, SiteC are my hosted application Names. But this three application are same project.

Thanks,
Pushparaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this sample. in layout page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if(window.location.href.indexOf('SiteA') !=-1)      
        {
        $('body').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{url(SiteA Theme)}">');
        }
        if(window.location.href.indexOf('SiteB') !=-1)      
        {
        $('body').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{url(SiteB Theme)}">');
        }
        if(window.location.href.indexOf('SiteC') !=-1)      
        {
        $('body').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{url(SiteC Theme)}">');
        }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! but the css is not applyig. do i need to change anything in bundle.config file???

Comment: please post the sample code. that may me easy to find the problem.

Comment: if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf("SiteA") != -1)
            {
                <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>
            }
            else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf("SiteB") != -1)
            {
                <link href="~/Content/Bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>
            }

Answer (score 0):

```
@{

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf("SiteA") != -1)
    {
        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>
    }
    else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf("SiteB") != -1)
    {
        <link href="~/Content/Bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>
    }
    else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf("SiteC") != -1)
    {
        <link href="~/Content/Bootstrap-theme2.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>
    }
}
```

I have removed the **bootstrap.css** in `bundle.config` and added above code in `_layout.chtml` page  tag.